# Use of unresolved identifier when referencing variable in do/catch block

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturesession, do-catch

I’m assigning a variable in a `do` / `catch` block, and then trying to reference that variable further down in my file. But when I do, I get the following error in Xcode:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'captureDeviceInput'

This is my code:

```swift
do {
    let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
} catch let error {
    print("\(error)")
    return
}

captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

captureSession?.addInput(input: captureDeviceInput as AVCaptureDeviceInput)
```

It seems Xcode’s not recognising the `captureDeviceInput` variable. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think I follow. The `do` block is a block, and so `captureDeviceInput` (and anything else declared inside it) is scoped to that block, you can't use it anywhere else

Comment: @crizzis Yes. That’s all I needed to know. As you can probably tell, I’m a Swift n00b!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`captureDeviceInput` is declared locally that means it's visible only in the `do` scope.

It's good habit to put all *good* code also in the `do` scope.

```
do {
    let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.addInput(input: captureDeviceInput as AVCaptureDeviceInput)
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply!